# Eclipse intellisense with gradle

Tags: eclipse, intellisense, gradle

when I edit **build.gradle** file in eclipse I want to have intellisense  to help me of words completion. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

SpringSource has a Gradle plug-in, which would get you that.

Prior to installing the Gradle Plug-in, I think I just used Preferences to always open build.gradle the Groovy Editor after I added a Groovy Nature to my project.